# How to Retry 503 response using Scrapy DownloadMiddleware?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

In my I have this

```
from scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry import RetryMiddleware

class Retry(RetryMiddleware):

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):

        if response.status == '503':
            logger.error("503 status returned: " + response.url)
            return self._retry(request,response, spider) or response

        logger.debug("response.status = "+str(response.status)+" from URL "+str(response.url))
        logger.debug(response.headers)

        return super(Retry, self).process_response(request, response, spider)


    def _retry(self, request,response, spider):

        logger.debug("Deleting session "+str(request.meta['sessionId']))
        self.delete_session(request.meta['sessionId'])

        logger.debug("Retrying URL: %(request)s", {'request': request})
        logger.debug("Response headers were:")
        logger.debug(request.headers)

        retryreq = request.copy()
        retryreq.headers['Authorization'] = crawlera_auth.strip()
        retryreq.headers['X-Crawlera-Session'] = 'create'

        retryreq.dont_filter = True
        return retryreq
```

And in my `settings.py` I have this

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'craigslist_tickets.retrymiddleware.Retry': 100,
    'craigslist_tickets.crawlera_proxy_middleware.CrawleraProxyMiddleware': 200
}
```

I can see output like `response.status =  200` for all URLs which are scraped successfully, but for the URLs which return `500` don't even are passing through `process_response`

I can only see in terminal

`[scrapy] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http:website.com> (failed 1 times): 503 Service Unavailable`

**SHORT QUESTION:**

I want to scrape URLs which return `503` again by passing through `process_response` method of my custom class `Retry`

Answer (score 1):

I had

`RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [503]` in settings.py so thats why Scrapy was handeling 503 code by itself.

Now I changed it to `RETRY_HTTP_CODES = []` now every URL that returns `503` is being passed via `process_response` method of `retrymiddleware.Retry` class ...

Mission accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

according to the documentation the `RetryMiddleware` [handles](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-http-codes) by deafult the `500` codes and because of its priority the response can not be reached by your code (please check the base [downloaders](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#downloader-middlewares-base). I would suggest to change the priority of your `Retry` middleware to `650`, like:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'craigslist_tickets.retrymiddleware.Retry': 650,
    'craigslist_tickets.crawlera_proxy_middleware.CrawleraProxyMiddleware': 200
}
```